# How do I output to a text file without getting an IO exception?

Tags: vb.net

I have this code.

```
Dim txtVern As String = String.Empty
    Try
        Using verSR As New StreamReader(appDataVersionLoc)
            txtVern = verSR.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim verFile As System.IO.FileStream
        verFile = System.IO.File.Create(appDataVersionLoc)
        Dim wWFERes As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Version file missing/corrupt, created a new one.")
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(appDataVersionLoc) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(appDataVersionLoc, "0.0.0.0", True)
        End If
    End Try
```

But when it tries to execute `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(appDataVersionLoc, "0.0.0.0", True)`, I get this error:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Dubstaphone\AppData\Roaming\TheArena\version.txt' because it is being used by another process.

How to I avoid this? What I did was I made it create a text file called "version.txt" if it doesn't already exist. Now I'm trying to write "0.0.0.0" to it, but it's giving me that error. By the way, "appDataVersionLoc" equals `GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\TheArena\version.txt"`
This variable works fine for everything else.

Thanks!

P.S.

I'm a complete noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.IO.File.Create` or `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText` may still hold a lock on the file. Use the `System.IO.File` `WriteAllText` and a `Using` statement.

If you use a Stream you should close/dispose of it. Better yet when dealing with files always use a `Using` statement.

Edit:

Example of creating a file

```
Using File.Create(path)
End Using
If File.Exists(appDataVersionLoc) Then
    File.WriteAllText(appDataVersionLoc, "0.0.0.0")
End If
```

or

```
Dim appDataFile = File.Create(path)
appDataFile.Close
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete newbie to VB, would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: Cool. Let us know how it goes. Chances are its the lock from `File.Create`